# ODBC Excel Workbook vs. Oracle Report

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc

Our organization is thinking of using ODBC-enabled Excel workbooks in addition to standard and Oracle custom reports. I'm thinking they should be used for things that aren't mission critical (e.g. getting a nice view of demand/sales vs. loading the demand or new orders into the system). Can anyone offer some best practices or guidelines for when an ODBC workbook is appropriate? Thanks for any advice...much appreciated as there isn't much on the web.